# C# Changing DLL app.config depending on consumer

Tags: c#, dll, app-config

I have a Class Library project containing some basic logic.

The DLL created by this project will be used in a few other projects.

I have a app.config file in the Class Library project with a couple of values the DLL uses.

When each consumer project will use the DLL, it has to change the values in the app.config

For example, if my DLL's app.config contains 3 settings: A, B, C,  then: 

The first consumer of the DLL will have A="a", B="aa", C="aaa" . 

The second consumer of the DLL will have A="t", B="tt", C="ttt" .

and so on...

From design point of view, what is the most clean way to achieve this scenario?

(It seems to me that the app.config should reside at the project that uses the DLL)

Thanks for your attention! :)

EDIT:

Most of my code in the DLL is consuming ASMX web service which includes it's .config . Each application that will use the DLL, has it's own WS address (the contract is identical). How can I inject the address of the service from the application into the DLL?

EDIT #2:

Now I have 2 config files:

 
1. In the class library project - contains the WCF client config.

 
2. In the application that uses the DLL - contains the config with the values for the DLL.

How can I inject values from the application's config into the DLL's config (for example the address of the endpoint) ?

Comment: Class libraries don't get their own config files. You can add one (or some tooling may automatically add one) but its unused at runtime. The only config file that's respected is the one for the main application.

Comment: Can you not hold these settings in a DB? And select the correct set at runtime from the consuming application?

Comment: @RubbleFord - Unfortunately, DB is not an option due to various constraints. So what is the best practice here?

Comment: Please look at the updates.

Answer (score 2):

Only applications have a .config file, so having a .config file in your class library is useless.
That means that the values should come from somewhere else
The options I can think of are:

1. Use the .config file of the application - **disadvantage**: The person that write the application need to know about your config values and add them. Most of the time he/she will find out about these setting when they will get exceptions for missing values.
2. Save values to a DB (or some other web service) if all your applications use the same DB this can be a good idea. Works nicely when you have a very limited number of applications. I use this for different values for production/test environments
3. Make every class that needs these values to get them in a contractor. **advantage**: no hints needed, the application programer will be aware to data. This is a clean interface. I would use this option if it's a customer specific project. **disadvantage**: lots of work for the applications programer

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I choose the 1st option, how can I read the application's .config from the DLL's code?

Comment: If you have many instances of your application (and the code exist once for each Web Service), just add the values you want to the config file and read them like:    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeKey"]

Comment: You mean I add the values to the config of the application using the DLL and in DLL's code read them via System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeKey"] ?

Comment: what do you mean by "I inject values"? each application has it's own config file

Comment: All the applications using the DLL share the same binding config found in the DLL config. But, the address of the endpoint in each application is different. I want the address to be configurable, so I put it in the config of the application. Now, I need to "inject" the address from my application into the DLL it uses.

Comment: If the dll is a part of the application, and the endpoint exists in the config of the application, the dll code can just read it from the same config.

Comment: Ok, but is it possible for the binding config to be in the DLL, and then let it use values from the application's config?

Comment: Someone has an answer? Thanks!