# Edit app.config form Dll file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dll

I have a C# 4.0 Windows Form solution in Visual Studio 2012. My DLL project has a app.config file.

To add app.config in DLL project I entered in Properties > Setting and add the string. After that VS 2012 created one for me. In this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398628/c-sharp-changing-dll-app-config-depending-on-consumer) I saw that it's impossible to 'export' an app.config from a DLL project. But if it is true, why does VS create this file for us?

How should I use a config file in DLL project?

Comment: It is a design flaw, System.Configuration is a pretty weak part of the framework.  The real option that's missing is to easily merge a DLL project's settings into the settings for the main EXE.  Which is not that easy to do smoothly, particularly undo-ing such a merge is hard to do.  It is still a programmer's job.  And that's a good thing, they wouldn't pay us the big bucks if anybody could do it.

Comment: Ok. But de exe project uses the DLL file, so I don't think thats a good idea to add a config dependency from Exe project. What is the best practice to do this?

Comment: Clearly the best practice is for a DLL to not use settings.  It ought to be configured by the EXE since it is the only agent that knows how the DLL is supposed to behave.  Expose properties.  Next best thing is to use simple XML serialization to read an .xml file at a well-known location.